# How to get tagname of XML with php?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

My XMLfile is as follows:

```
<Project>
  <ProjectInformation>
    <FileHeader>IDGIS_PROJECT</FileHeader>
    <Details ProjectID="0" ProjectName="" Description="" StartDate="02/05/2012 00:00:00 AM" OwnerShip="" LastModified="01/01/0001 00:00:00 AM" Datum="WGS_84" Projection="CYL" NoSignificantDecimals="3" ZoomCurrent="303601" RasterHeight="0" Background="-1">Project Details</Details>
    <ProjectBounds XMin="25.4579486950873" YMin="44.7183808936148" XMax="26.5953949808977" YMax="45.5345534542584" ExtentBounds="no">Bounds</ProjectBounds>
  </ProjectInformation>
  <Layers>
    <Layer ID="2" Description="" MinZoom="1" MaxZoom="1000000000" Visible="3" RemotHostType="LocalFile" RemotHost="" FolderName="Prahova_Highways" Path="" LayerStatus="ReadWrite">
</Layers>
```

I am unable to get child notes of Projectinformation. i want to get all attributes of Details and Project bounds. This thing is very easy in Java but i dunt know how to do it with php.
My code for getting childnotes of projectinformation is as follows:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('oglPrahova/prahova.GIS');

$x=$xmlDoc->documentElement;
var_dump($x);

$x = $xmlDoc->->getElementsByTagName('ProjectInformation');  

foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item) {
    print $i->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: try with `$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('ProjectInformation'); ` you have an extra `->` in you code.

Comment: I would suggest using XPath to query XML file and SimpleXML PHP library.

Comment: i have tried it now i am getting $X but i am not getting its childnodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SimpleXML :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
'<Project>
    <ProjectInformation>
        <FileHeader>IDGIS_PROJECT</FileHeader>
        <Details ProjectID="0" ProjectName="" Description="" StartDate="02/05/2012 00:00:00 AM" OwnerShip="" LastModified="01/01/0001 00:00:00 AM" Datum="WGS_84" Projection="CYL" NoSignificantDecimals="3" ZoomCurrent="303601" RasterHeight="0" Background="-1">Project Details</Details>
        <ProjectBounds XMin="25.4579486950873" YMin="44.7183808936148" XMax="26.5953949808977" YMax="45.5345534542584" ExtentBounds="no">Bounds</ProjectBounds>
    </ProjectInformation>
    <Layers>
        <Layer ID="2" Description="" MinZoom="1" MaxZoom="1000000000" Visible="3" RemotHostType="LocalFile" RemotHost="" FolderName="Prahova_Highways" Path="" LayerStatus="ReadWrite" />
    </Layers>
</Project>');

foreach($xml->ProjectInformation->Details->attributes() as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key : $value ";
}
foreach($xml->ProjectInformation->ProjectBounds->attributes() as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key : $value ";
}
```

As a more generic answer, you can use :

```
foreach($xml->ProjectInformation->children() as $child)
{
    foreach($child->attributes() as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "$key : $value ";
    }
}
```

You can also use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/fr/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), as said in a comment.

Comment: but how to give XML file to SimpleXMlelement?

Comment: is there any method like $xml->ProjectInformation->childNodes?

Comment: To load the xml, either give it as a string or use the [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-file.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('ProjectInformation');  

foreach ($x->childNodes as $nodename) {
    if( $nodename->nodeName == 'FileHeader' ){
        echo $nodename->nodeName. " - " . $nodename->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}
```

Where `$nodename->nodeName` holds all the child node names like `FileHeader, Details, etc.`

Comment: still not getting childs